# USB Hub not working with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

Earlier I just had my mouse plug into my laptop while using Ubuntu 16.04 and it was perfectly fine!

I came home and plugged in my USB Hub (First time w/ Ubuntu) and that has my keyboard and mouse connected to it. Doesn't work, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had problems booting Ubuntu with USB Hub plugged in. Booting Ubuntu with USB Hub unplugged solved the problem. Then I plugged the USB hub in after booting Ubuntu. This might work for you too.

A few days later I was able to boot Ubuntu with the USB hub plugged in from the beginning and the problem didn't repeat.

HTH.

Comment: Also worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04